# Validation .passes if null/empty/length == 0 doesn't fire

Tags: aurelia

Validation doesn't seem to be called when the property has no value.
This is the code I'm using to try and make it work:

```
.ensure('baseContent.SetNamePrint').passes((name) =>
{
    var webNameLength = this.baseContent.SetNameWeb.length;
    var printNameLength = name.length;

    console.log(webNameLength);
    console.log(printNameLength);

    if ((webNameLength > 1 && webNameLength < 51) || (printNameLength > 1 && printNameLength < 51)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}).withMessage('Web Name or Print Name is Required')
```

The passes only fires when the value of the property changes to something with a length, when it's empty (a blank string) nothing happens.

What I need is for the .passes() to be called every time there is a change to the value not just when there is a change and it has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what I wanted I ended up with the following code.

```
this.validator = this.validation.on(this)
    .ensure('SetNameWeb', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['SetNamePrint', 'SetNameWeb'])})
        .if(() => { return this.HasImageEitherPrintNameOrWebName === false })
            .isNotEmpty().withMessage('or "Print Name" is required')
            .hasLengthBetween(0, 50)
        .endIf()
    .ensure('SetNamePrint', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['SetNameWeb', 'SetNamePrint'])})
        .if(() => { return this.HasImageEitherPrintNameOrWebName === false })
            .isNotEmpty().withMessage('or "Web Name" is required')
            .hasLengthBetween(0, 50)
        .endIf()
```

This gave me the functionality I needed with both of the fields being updated with each other.

However there was a bug in the aurelia code with the way it handles computedFrom that needed fixing to get this to work.

This problem was with aurelia-validation@0.6.8 though and there is now a new version which works in a completely different way so my recommendation is to update if you're having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to additionally constraint the target property with `isNotEmpty`.

```
.ensure('baseContent.SetNamePrint').isNotEmpty().passes(...
```

From the documentation:

> The isNotEmpty rule is always checked first before any other
>   validation rule. This means that without the isNotEmpty rule, the
>   .hasMinLength(5) rule would still consider a value of '' as valid
>   because the field is allowed to be empty.

PS: I heard that aurelia-validation is under rewriting. Perhaps that's why I can't find the documentation from the master branch anymore, but in another branch [here](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/sunset-0.6.0/doc/Intro.md)

Comment: I have this code mirrored but slightly changed on another property, so basically one of the two properties is required which means it is valid for this to be empty so that wouldn't work for me, any other ideas?

Comment: @AndyGould So what you want is a validation involving multiple properties. Consider using `onValidate()` to "register a callback that is called when the entire subject is validated". A caveat is the callback is not automatically fired when a property value changed. In your case, I would constrain each property as much as possible (e.g length b/w 1 and 51), and use `onValidate` for thing like "X or Y is required" on form submit.

Comment: Another more ad hoc option is to have a computed, such as `webOrPrintName`, and apply validation on it instead.